# Dragstart event behaves differently in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, preventdefault

I need to handle a `dragstart` event and avoid `click` event (because it has another handler). This works well in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox it fires up the `click` event also. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
Drag and release the circle:<br>
<a href="#">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2264%22%20cy%3D%2264%22%20r%3D%2264%22%20style%3D%22fill%3A%2300ccff%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {

  $(document).on('dragstart', function(e) {
    console.log('dragstart');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('img').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('img click');
  });

  $('a').click(function(e){
    console.log('a click');
  })

});
```

**Codepen:** [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQqbge/)

**NOTE:** you have to stop dragging when you're still over the image.

To be more clear: I'm making a slider, and in `dragstart` event I look for mouse movement direction, that's why I set `preventDefault` - so the image won't be dragged. Then I make calculations and animation in necessary direction. Images in this slider has `click` event handler to show bigger picture, that's why I don't need this extra-click event after `dragstart`.

So how to avoid this `click` event in Firefox?